# HBase Filters: ColumnPrefixFIlter and SingleColumnValueFilter

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I have an HBase table, person. I'm using ColumnPrefixFilter and SingleColumnValueFilter to fetch details from HBase table

For suppose, I have entries like below-

```
ROW_KEY     COLUMN+CELL
p1          column='attr:id',value=p1_03
p1          column='details:name_1',value=xyz
p2          column='attr:id',value=p2_04
p2          column='details:name_2',value=xyz
```

I need to fetch the row_key where name is **xyz** and id is **p1_03**. Tried the below query but it results in both row keys.

```
scan 'person', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('attr','id',=,'binary:p1_03') AND (ColumnPrefixFilter('name') AND ValueFilter(=,'xyz'))"}
```

**Output:**

```
ROW         COLUMN+CELL
p1          column='details:name_1',value=xyz
p2          column='details:name_2',value=xyz
```

I need to get only one row key **p1**

Comment: What if you just apply the `SingleColumnValueFilter`?

Comment: @BenWatson Column **name** is auto-incremental, meaning, for row_key **p1** we can have many columns name_1, name_2...name_n, I do not know where **xyz** is. So, I opted for ColumnPrefixFilter

Comment: My point is: does each filter individually do what you expect it to? Break down your problem into smaller problems and see where the error actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SingleColumnValueFilter with AND/OR conditions.

Here since you use different column families, hence use following:

```
scan 'person', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('attr','id',=,'binary:p1_03') AND  SingleColumnValueFilter('details','name*',=,'binary:xyz')"}
```